# Change an array into an sql query PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array `$contact` that looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Textbox
            [label] => Company
            [name] => company
            [properties] => a:2:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}
            [language] => EN
            [weight] => 1
            [nid] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Textbox
            [label] => First name
            [name] => first_name
            [properties] => a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}
            [language] => EN
            [weight] => 2
            [nid] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Textbox
            [label] => Last Name
            [name] => last_name
            [properties] => a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}
            [language] => EN
            [weight] => 3
            [nid] => 5
        )
```

And I'd like to change it to :

```
INSERT INTO `form` (`nid`, `language`, `label`, `name`, `type`, `properties`, `options`, `weight`) VALUES
( 5, 'EN', 'Société', 'societe', 'Textbox', 'a:2:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', NULL, 1),
( 5, 'EN', 'First name', 'first_name', 'Textbox', 'a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', NULL, 2),
( 5, 'EN', 'Last Name', 'last_name', 'Textbox', 'a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', NULL, 3);
```

So I tried this :

```
function insert_contact($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){       
        if ($key == 'fields'){
            $columns = array_keys($value);
            $values = array_values($value);
        }
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".'form' . "` (`".implode("`, `", $columns)."`)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $values)."') ;";
    return $sql;

}
```

And it worked for the only the first element of the array,but when I do :

```
    foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
        var_dump(insert_contact( $var[$key]));
     }
```

It displays me this error : `Notice: Undefined variable: columns` 
Is there a way to avoid this error and generate a clean sql query? Thanks

Comment: What is the array you pass into `insert_contact()`. Ensure it contains the key `fields`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about it since I used the function for other purposes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `fields` in your array. The reason the code is working for the first element is because:

```
if ($key == 'fields'){
```

will be true if $key is `0` (due to type coercion).

Try:

```
function insert_contact($array){
    $values = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){       
        $columns = array_keys($value);
        $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", array_values($value))."')";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".'form' . "` (`".implode("`, `", $columns)."`)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ".implode(',', $values) .";";
    return $sql;

}
```

Please note if it's at all possible that the `$array` or it's contents can come from user input you don't want to use the values in a query without  first escaping them.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Although I should add that if `$key` was a string this wont be the case, numeric keys are always stored as an integer however.

Answer (score 0):

Jim wrote a good answer, but he never explained the actual error:

On line 8 of your function you call the variable `$columns`. However, since `$key == 'fields'` evaluates to false it never gets set. That's why the error says there's an undefined variabe named 'columns' in the script.

You can only call variables that have been previously defined.